# Time complexity with Tree data structure

Tags: python, tree, big-o, complexity-theory

i'm currently working on a Tree data structure in python. At the moment, i am trying to calculate subtree values, where a subtree value equals the largest value of a node in a given node's subtree. E.g. For the given tree:

```
       A(5)
       / \
     C(2) D(8)
      |
     B(10)
```

The subtree value of C would be 10, the subtree value of A would be 10 and the subtree value of D would be 8 etc. I am trying to reduce the complexity of the following code from O(n^2) to O(n). That is, im trying to move up the tree without using a nested loop. I have tried this with recursion but i am not too great at recursion hence the iterative solution below. Any help would be appreciated. Also, is it possible to do this without a recursive solution?

```
         node = subtree_a
         while node.parent != None:
             children = node.parent.children
             for child in children:
                 if (child.subtree_value > node.parent.subtree_value):
                     node.parent.set_subtree_val(child.subtree_value)
             node = node.parent\
```

Answer (score 1):

A subtree's value only depends on the nodes lower than it on the tree, so there's absolutely no reason to have the bottom-up outer loop in your code.

A very simple top-down recursive approach would be:

```
def calc_subtree_value(node):
    val = node.value
    for child in node.children: # we don't need a base case, this forks for leaf nodes too
        calc_subtree_value(child)
        if child.subtree_value > val:
            val = child.subtree_value
    node.subtree_value = val
```

This takes O(N) time where N is the number of nodes in the subtree, as it visits each one exactly once. As I note in the comment, we don't need an explicit base case because the loop over the children does what we want (nothing) if there are no children to check for larger subtree values.

Comment: This does make sense, thanks. Is the last line meant to equal "val" instead of "max_val"?

Comment: Also, is it possible to do this without recursion?

Comment: Yep, sorry, `max_val` was a typo, I'd renamed the variable after writing the code and missed one spot. You could solve this problem with only iteration, but it would be a little tedious. The recursion is not tail recursion, so converting it usually needs a stack or similar data structure to handle what the recursive call tree normally does for you automatically. Recursion is pretty natural for tree algorithms, so I'd got with it unless you have a specific reason to avoid it.